# how can i avoid having to get data very time i change view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angular and a bit of a novice generally. any examples i have looked at seem to use a service to request a collection in a controller for a view and attach it to the scope for that controller. when you change view and hence controller the controller is destroyed and therefore when you go back into the view you have to request the data for the view again. this seems like a lot of uneccessary fetching of the same data.

also say there were many records in my collection it could take a while to make this request and slow the loading of the data. say for example you had a a calander app with a week view and an average of 30 events a week, the collection for a year would have 1500 events would you fetch the events for the week in view and then fetch the rest of the events after that and how would you go about doing this. or would you just fetch the events for each week as you incremented the week. apologies for the lack of code but i havent written it yet as i am trying to figure out how i should write it.

Comment: if you don't expect the data to change during the time the app is in use, you could cache the data in a service. In other words, keep the controller as is, however the called service for fetching the data would know whether to make an HTTP call or return the cached data

Comment: As jusopi said, you should use a service and basics getters/setters...

Comment: the data would change during the time the app is in use. is there a way to keep the originally fetched data when i change controller can i keep it in a service i.e. use one service to request and update data and call this from another service where i store the data. the data would then persist when model is destroyed.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. But adding a cache consumes memory, makes the code more complex (you need to update or invalidate the cache, deal with errors, etc.), and many apps show data that can be modified by several concurrent users (including just yourself, on multiple devices or browsers), which leads to stale caches. Just loading the data when it's needed is much simpler and fast enough for most of the cases.